# AngularJS templated index with gulp

Tags: angularjs, gulp

So everytime i add/remove/rename a file of my angularjs project the index.html file is changed accorgingly by the inject gulp process.
The consequence is that if in a team more people change file paths the index.html file is constantly conflicted and must be manually merged.

How can i solve this?

**I think that a solution can be**:
index template file that is versioned but only contains placeholders for the injection of external scripts and then a gulp process that builds at runtime a temporary index.html file that is not versioned.

How can i achieve this?

gulpfile.js ->
https://gist.github.com/bolza-admedo/32fec5026d2433c346fd

gulp.config.js -> https://gist.github.com/bolza-admedo/2712631f093a901be73c

Answer (score 0):

add your resulting `index.html` to `.gitignore`, I assume you are using GIT as your source control.

```
.gitignore:
  dist/index.html
```

you make your changes to `index.html`, then your gulp process builds another index.html that is placed in `dist` folder for example, that is along with other build artefacts, like JS and CSS are excluded from git repository

rule of thumb: everything that is produced by your build - is excluded from git

Comment: Ehm, if i git-ignore the index file what will happen when i'll want to make a change on the index? I just want the list of scripts out.

Comment: Yesss that's exactly what i proposed in the text of my question, but what i asked is how to do that.

Comment: @Bolza show me your `gulpfile`, and I will suggest edits

Comment: from what I can see in your `gulpfile`, resulting index.html is being dumped here `var client = './src/client/';`

Comment: Yes, my file explorer already told me that. What's the point?